# При наследования от базового класса, выдаёт ошибку

Tags: c#

```
public class Person 
{ 
        
    
    public string Name{get;} 
    public string LastName{get;private set;}
    public int Age{get;} 
    public long Id{get;}    
    public Person(string name,string l_name,int age)//конструктор
    {
        // проверку на вход сделать позже
        Name = name;
        LastName = l_name;
        Age = age;
        
        Random rand = new();
        Id = rand.Next(3000000,11000000);           
    
    }

//============
public  class Test : Person//тут ошибка cs7036 и cs 8861
{

//...... 

}
```

Так вот, ошибку я понял,  надо передать конструктору параметры
Сделать

```
public class Test : Person(Тут указать параметры)
```

А можно ли их не указывать? Обойти как нибудь это? Вообще конструктор наследуется от базового класса? И главный вопрос, зачем мне туда передавать параметры. Или мы тем самым через базовый конструктор будем инициализировать дочерние классы теперь? И в параметры нужно передавать свойства дочернего класса?

Comment: Вы можете создать класс, у которого конструктор **требует** параметры, без указания этих параметров? Нет. Ну так почему тут вы вдруг должны хотеть чего либо другого? У вас есть класс, который требует параметры, вы их обязаны туда передать. Только вы параметры передаете не правильно, при наследовании вы должны создать конструктор, который будет делать что-то такое `: base(параметры)`, где "параметры" - это любой способ передачи значений в конструктор (пример `public Test(string name): base(name, "123" 20){ }` - `name` из конструктора, другие параметры "забиваем гвоздями" и не требуем).

Comment: К сожалению пока не до конца понял, пример бы.я так понимаю у наследника нужно тоже создать конструктор, который инициализируется значениями базового класса?

Comment: public class Test : Person { public Test(string name) : base(name, "test", 20) { /* конструктор */ } } примерно так

Comment: Я вам пример дал, вы попробуйте перед тем как писать. Ваш класс требует параметры, которые обязательно должны быть заданы при инициализации, ну а раз от него наследуется другой класс, то ответственность за реализацию перекладывается на наследника, он обязан иметь конструктор, который через [base](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base#example-2) задаст нужные параметры родителю, ну а что будет требовать конструктор наследника, это уже без разницы, в примере выше я вам показал, что он требует только `name`, который передает конструктору родителя.

Comment: В тексте ошибок явно указывается с чем проблема. Что именно в них непонятно?